# Phrase for offering first choice from only options where you don't mind the rejects?

Tags: phrase-requests

Here's the scenario: I have been sent to get takeaway food or drinks for, say, two friends or co-workers and myself. I do not know their food preferences. When I get to the counter, I find three diverse options **that I would be happy to eat**, and buy them all. Then I meet my friends, offer them the first choices between the meals I bought, and happily accept the final reject for myself.

It isn't a perfect system (their first preference may have been something I don't like to eat), but there is a good chance there is a choice that they are satisfied with, and when we are busy, it avoids extended phone discussions about menus.

This is a common-enough scenario - I am sure there is a phrase to describe it. Have you heard of one?

Comment: Yeah, but who picks first among those two? You devised something that works for you but might not work for them.

Comment: I question that this is a common (or desirable) scenario. There's a better way to force a choice. Prior to ordering, tell them what you will be ordering, so they know what they will have to choose from. Nothing helps people decide faster than telling them the consequence of their indecision.

Comment: @TinfoilHat: Sure. [Shotgun rules apply](https://www.shotgunrules.com/).

Comment: @jimm101: I find this scenario most common when I am supporting my friends who are busy. I might be picking up food for them while they are on stage, running a marathon, doing an exam, arguing in court, etc. This isn't about getting the perfect meal, but getting a satisfactory meal without fuss.

Comment: With two people, it would just be called giving the other person first choice (as you call it in the question). I think this could be extended to more than 2 people.

Comment: The most relevant fact in the scenario has been left out.  Did your friends send you and not express any preference when doing so?

Comment: @TimR: The first sentence says "I have been sent", although I don't know why it makes a difference if I decided to surprise them. The second sentence says "I do not know their food preferences." If I did, the phrase would be "picking up my friends' take-out orders".

Comment: My key take-aways (pun intended) from asking here and friends IRL: (1) It seems I encounter this situation more than others. I wonder if that is because I am so generous and helpful when my friends need support, or because I am cantankerous and don't want to live my life hanging out in takeaway restaurants taking detailed food orders over the phone. (2) I am meeting a lot of cynicism that suggests I am trying to "win" this interaction with my friends, rather than feed them with minimum fuss.

Comment: If you were sent by your friends and they didn't express any preferences, they have to accept whatever it is you bring back for them to eat. They should have sized you up and realized you'd bring them kibble.

Comment: Of course this is highly realistic: your friends would have texted you elaborate decision trees while you were on your way: "If the taco salad doesn't look fresh, ..."

Comment: @TimR: There you go again assuming I am trying to "win" by shafting my friends. Yes, they do have to accept whatever I bring, but I am making it as good as I can for them, given the constraints. I am not only bringing them a decent meal, I am bringing them a (small) choice and happily eating their rejects.

Comment: If they did not let their preferences be known, you won't know anything about what they like, what they dislike, what they might be allergic to or might refuse to eat on ethical or religious grounds. So it's possible that none of the choices may be good for them, even though you're letting them choose ahead of you. If none of these factors has any bearing on the question you have in mind, perhaps you should find a better example than food. Perhaps three lottery tickets.

Comment: @TimR: Yes. If my friends agreed that I should get them food, and declined to ever tell me that they are secretly vegans, coeliacs or practising Muslims, there is a risk this will fail, and that is a risk I am willing to take. If I decided to get them food without co-ordinating at all, the risk is higher, and yet I am still willing to take it! I try to choose a diverse set of safe foods - go for mild sauces, get a vegetarian option, etc. to reduce the risk.

Answer (score 1):

**Fair Division**

I question your (sole) criteria for the food choices as things *you* would like to eat. For example, if you're a vegetarian or like very spicy foods, you may well be unfairly limiting their choices to ensure you wind up with something you'd really enjoy. If, one the other hand, you get one fish, one meat, and one vegetable dish (or, say, one meat and two vegetable, salad, or pasta dishes) you may have a better chance of pleasing everyone, as long as you're willing to eat any one of the three. Show up with one *really* spicy dish and your friends won't buy your "reject" label. PBJ all around?

---

Putting that aside (as your friends may do with their food), I believe your problem comes under the heading of **fair-division**:

> **Fair division is the problem in game theory of dividing a set of resources among several people who have an entitlement to them so that
> each person receives their due share.** That problem arises in various
> real-world settings such as division of inheritance, partnership
> dissolutions, divorce settlements, electronic frequency allocation,
> airport traffic management, and exploitation of Earth observation
> satellites. It is an active research area in mathematics, economics
> (especially social choice theory), dispute resolution, etc. **The
> central tenet of fair division is that such a division should be
> performed by the players themselves, maybe using a mediator but
> certainly not an arbiter as only the players really know how they
> value the goods.**
>
> The archetypal fair division algorithm is divide and choose. It
> demonstrates that two agents with different tastes can divide a cake
> such that each of them believes that he got the best piece. The
> research in fair division can be seen as an extension of this
> procedure to various more complex settings.
>
> **There are many different kinds of fair division problems, depending on
> the nature of goods to divide, the criteria for fairness, the nature
> of the players and their preferences, and other criteria for evaluating the quality of the division.**
> [*Fair Division* in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_division)

A classic fair-division problem is **[fair cake cutting](https://Fair%20cake-cutting)**. If you are two people, it's a simple solution: one person cuts the dessert and the other has first choice of the two pieces. You are responsible for the size of your piece and your dinner partner is responsible for the size of theirs.

> **Here’s why mathematicians are so interested in cake cutting**
>
> Ariel Procaccia has thought a lot about how to cut cake over the last
> 15 years. That’s partly because the Harvard computer scientist has
> three children who among them have celebrated more than two dozen
> birthdays. He knows what it’s like to stand with a knife before a
> layered masterpiece, frosted with buttercream and chocolate curls,
> while pressed on all sides by small partygoers who instinctively
> recognize when someone else gets a better slice.
>
> But it’s also because much of Procaccia’s work focuses on exploring
> the mathematical rules for dividing stuff up. One way to do that is to
> think abstractly about dessert. For more than 75 years, he and other
> researchers trying to formalize fairness have been asking the
> deceptively simple question: **What methods for cutting a cake guarantee
> that everyone who shows up to the party is happy with what they get?**
> [Stephen Ornes in *Science News*, September 8, 2023](https://www.sciencenews.org/article/cake-cutting-math-problem-fairness-envy)

Comment: Re: "I would like to eat." Well, I could substitute with "I would be satisfied to eat." but this system relies on everyone being moderately easy to satisfy - i.e. would accept 8 or 9 out of every ten choices on the menu. If I am a vegetarian, yes, all three choices will be vegetarian. If my friends have opposed dietary choices to me, this system fails. If I strongly prefer spicy dishes, the system fails because I might end up with a non-spicy dish.

Comment: I understand fair division/fair cake cutting, but this seems different - typically the metaphorical cake is fixed. Also, I am not maximising my happiness with my meal. I am minimising coordination (while trying to have a good chance of three-way satisfaction).

Comment: Consider the Wiki article's explanation of the general category--I think your situations fits. // With regard to your meal choices, the problem exists only if you refuse to eat *anything but* spicy dishes. If that isn't the case, and you know nothing about your friends food habits, why assume they are in a special class? // ELU isn't the place to ask about a *specific* solution to your situation, but rather a name/category for the type of problem. Perhaps someone will have an answer you like better :)

Answer (score 1):

This is surely a modern *version* of *Hobson's Choice*. That is giving a choice that is not much of a choice. In Hobson's use there is no choice though several may be presented. You can have a choice of A or a choice of A. These are always presented as if they are perfectly different and fair though they turn out not quite so. Not as obvious as the old model T Ford: any color you want as long as it's black. In your use you are limiting their choices to your  choices, those you would prefer so that whatever they choose you are still the winner. As such you come out ahead every time as they must eat what they may not like. Where Hobson's original may be no choice yours gives them choices with the same result; you win. If they used the same method on you then you would see what a cheat it is to settle for someone else's dinner.

I would guess they might choose someone else to get the food for them. Bon Appetite.

https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/hobsons-choice.html

Comment: I can see why it is related. My friends have to fight over which of the three choices they get, rather than having a free choice over the whole menu (with the benefit of not being interrupted to make decisions they don't care much about). However, "Hobson's Choice" is no choice at all, so it feels wrong.

Comment: Note: I don't come ahead every time. I may end up with my *third* choice. My advantage is I never do worse than my third choice. The last time this happened, I was shouting late-night doner kebabs for my friend who was too busy running a comedy show to be bothered with questions about what sauce to add. They weren't thinking "I should get someone else to buy me a free dinner next time."

Comment: But you did have *a* choice, which at least one of the other two won’t.